# Trying to reference each item of custom type for tableView cells

Tags: json, swift, struct

I am parsing data from a JSON file and I've created a struct to hold that data. I am trying to display each item of the custom struct in a tableView, but I'm getting stuck on how I should reference each item.

Here's my struct:

```
struct Country: Codable {

    var id: Int
    var country: String
    var capital: String
    var nationalLanguage: [String]
    var population: Int
    
}
```

And here is my table view controller. Right now I only know how to reference a single item in my custom type. This obviously sets all of the cells to that one item.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var countryItem: Country?
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cells", for: indexPath)
        
        if let country = countryItem {
            cell.textLabel!.text = String(country.population)
        }
        return cell
    }
        
}
```

When I print out my countryItem variable, this is what I get:

```
Country(id: 1, country: "United States", capital: "Washington D.C.", nationalLanguage: ["English"], population: 328239523)
```

Do I need to somehow set that as an array so I can refer to each item individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED:

**Option1**

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var countryItem: Country?

    var arrayStrings: [String] {
        guard let countryItem = countryItem else { return [] }
        return [
            "\(countryItem.id)",
            countryItem.country,
            countryItem.capital,
            countryItem.nationalLanguage.joined(separator: ", "),
            "\(countryItem.population)",
        ]
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayStrings.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cells", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel!.text = arrayStrings[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
        
}
```

**Option2**

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var countryItem: Country?
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return countryItem == nil ? 0 : 5
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cells", for: indexPath)
        
        let text: String
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            text = "\(countryItem!.id)"
        case 1:
            text = countryItem!.country
        case 2:
            text = countryItem!.capital
        case 3:
            text = countryItem!.nationalLanguage.joined(separator: ", ")
        case 4:
            text = "\(countryItem!.population)"
        default:
            break
        }

        cell.textLabel!.text = text
        return cell
    }
        
}
```

If you all you want is just display string representation of all fields in your struct, then yes, convert them into a single array of string and use reusable cells to render.

If you need different styles for each field, then you may not need an array, just create some custom cells and then assign data for them from the struct.

Or maybe you don't even need a table view here since I see you have only one Country and no reusable needed here. Just create a custom view with 5 (maybe) labels and display your data.

For some reason, you still need a table view, then create a single cell that can display all information for your `country`.

Comment: There are multiple countries that are being used. I've tried to create an array of my custom Country object, but it returns an array with the count of 1 and everything in that one array item. See the final code snippet in my main post to see what I mean. What I need help with is displaying the first cell with the id, second cell with the country name, third cell with with the capital, etc.

Comment: I still can't imagine what you are trying to achieve. Could you tell me more? like is there many of `Country` you are trying to display in a single table view? Do you want to display each field of one `Country` in a single cell?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have a table view controller which has the countries names in the cells. When they select a country they are sent to another table view controller which I want to display other data in my struct in each cell. Cell 1 would have if for that specific country, then country name, then capital, etc. Does that make sense? I know how to refer to a specific item in my Country type (Ex. countryItem.id), but I don’t know how to refer to each item for each individual cell.

Comment: Okay, it's now quite clear to me. You have 2 options now. The first one is creating an array to hold all strings for all cells. You can do it simply by convert your struct into an array of String `let arrayStrings = [country.id, country.capital, ...]`. And then in the `cellForRow` just get the appropriate item by using indices. The second one is just using Swift's `switch case` to get the appropriate data for specific row index path. Let's say row index 0 is for display `id`, row index 2 is for `country` and so on...

Comment: @cookiecutter See my updated answer to understand what I'm saying about

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. It’s late here so I’m going to try these approaches in the morning.

Comment: Sure. Don't forget to let me know the result

Comment: Thank you! Option 1 worked out. What is this syntax called: `var arrayStrings: [String] { ... }`? Is that a closure? How did you know to use that here?

Comment: It's called `computed property`. There are so many kinds of property in Swift. You can get more fun here: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html

Answer (score 0):

Hope it can help you.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var countryItem = [Country]()

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return countryItem.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cells", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel!.text = countryItem[indexPath.row].country
    
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: That's unfortunately not quite what I'm looking for. I'm trying to hit each item in my custom struct to display in my tableView. So I wan to display id in row 1, country in row 2, capital in row 3, etc. Also, returning an array of Country gives me everything that I grabbed from my JSON file. I appreciate the comment though.

Comment: I see, you can design 1 row according to the stacks with uiview in cell, it will be easier